# Prisma multiple optional sort properties, orderBy

Tags: sorting, sql-order-by, prisma

I am working on a GET-endpoint in my Prisma back-end to retrieve all tasks.

Currently, I want to add multiple sort options using `sortBy`

In my code below there are two sortBy options. However, I cannot seem to make both of them work, just the first object in the `orderBy[]` array.

```
router.get("/tasks", async (req, res) => {
  var currentPage = req.query.page || 1;
  const listPerPage = 45;
  const offset = (currentPage - 1) * listPerPage;

  var category = req.query.category;
  var sortQuery = req.query.sort;
  var sort = sortQuery.split("_");

  var idSortBy = "asc";
  var dateSortBy = "asc";

  if (sort !== undefined) {
    if (sort[0] === "id") {
      idSortBy = sort[1];
    } else {
      dateSortBy = sort[1];
    }
  }

  const allTasks = await prisma.task.findMany({
    orderBy: [
      {
        createdAt: dateSortBy,
      },
      {
        id: idSortBy,
      },
    ],
    where: { category: category },
    skip: offset,
    take: listPerPage,
  });

  res.json({
    data: allTasks,
    meta: { page: currentPage },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution where all sorting options are parsed to the orderBy in the findMany function.

```
router.get("/tasks", async (req, res) => {
  var currentPage = req.query.page || 1;
  const listPerPage = 45;
  var offset = (currentPage - 1) * listPerPage;

  var category = req.query.category;

  var sort = req.query.sort.split("_");
  var orderByObject = {};
  orderByObject[sort[0]] = sort[1];
  var orderBySet = [orderByObject];

  const allTasks = await prisma.task.findMany({
    where: { category: category },
    skip: offset,
    take: listPerPage,
    orderBy: orderBySet,
  });

  res.json({
    data: allTasks,
    meta: { page: currentPage },
  });
});
```